# display effect on an element on button click in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a simple counter with 2 buttons- increment and decrement.
What I want to achieve is whenever the increment button is clicked, the value of the counter(displayed as an h3) should increase by 1 and the h3 should have an animation of text shadow and change color to green. Similarly when I click decrement, it should have the animation and change color to red.

The issue I am facing is that when I click the decrement button after clicking the increment button everything works fine and vice versa. But when I click the same button twice, I am not being able to see the animation. How to achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
function App() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

  const [btnclass, setBtnClass]=useState("")
  const valueRef= useRef(0)
  const decrement=()=>{
    setBtnClass("minus")
    setValue(value-1)
  }

  const increment=()=>{
    setBtnClass("plus")
    setValue(value+1)
  }

  return (
          <div className="App">
            <div className='row'>
              <button className="btn" style={{backgroundColor:'red'}} onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
              <h3 ref={valueRef} className={btnclass} style={{color: `${btnclass=="minus"? "red": "green"}`}}>{value}</h3>
              <button className="btn" onClick={increment} >Increment</button>
            </div>
          </div>
  );
}
```

The CSS code:

```
.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: x-large;
  padding: 5px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.minus {
  animation-name: minus;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes minus {
  from {
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px red;
    color: red;
  }
}

.plus {
  animation-name: plus;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes plus {
  from {
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px green;
    color: green;
  }
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: button;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes button {
  from {
    background-color: aqua;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }

  to {
    background-color: pink;
    transform: rotateX(30deg);
  }
}
```

What I think is going on- since on clicking the same button twice, the value of btnclass is not changing and thus the animation is not showing? Am I correct? If not please tell me the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching on SO I found a solution. There is an event called `onAnimationEnd`. Editing as such served my purpose:

```
<h3 className={btnclass} onAnimationEnd={()=>setBtnClass("")} style={{color: `${btnclass=="minus"? "red": "green"}`}}>{value}</h3>
```